# How to pass data from Syncfusion Data Grid to Sidebar in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion data grid to display information. When item in data grid is clicked I would like to show this infomation(and some additional update/delete buttons) in a Syncfusion sidebar. My question is what would be normal flow to pass this information from data grid to sidebar?

Here is code sample that use - when data grid item is clicked, function is called to manually find items in sidebar and set their values. It works, but seems very amateur to me. Is there a way how I could pass the underlying model (ProjectUser) to sidebar instead of setting values manually? Or maybe I should use totally different approach to achieve this?

```
@using Syncfusion.EJ2
@{
    List<ProjectUser> ProjectTeam = new List<ProjectUser>
    {
        new ProjectUser{Name="UserA", Email="info@email.com"},
        new ProjectUser{Name="UserB", Email="info@email.com"},
        new ProjectUser{Name="UserC", Email="info@email.com"}
    };
}

<div class="control-section">
<div id="wrapper" class="apimaincontent">
    <div>
        <ejs-grid id="Grid" dataSource="ProjectTeam" rowSelected="rowSelected" allowSelection="true">
            <e-grid-selectionsettings type="Single"></e-grid-selectionsettings>
            <e-grid-columns>
                <e-grid-column field="Name" headerText="Name" textAlign="Left" width="60"></e-grid-column>
                <e-grid-column field="Empolyer" headerText="Empolyer" width="60"></e-grid-column>
            </e-grid-columns>
        </ejs-grid>
    </div>
</div>
    <ejs-sidebar id="left-sidebar" showBackdrop="false" type="Push" width="260px" target=".apimaincontent">
        <e-content-template>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="memberName" class="sub-title"></div>
                <div id="memberEmail" class="sub-title"></div>
            </div>
        </e-content-template>
    </ejs-sidebar>
</div>

<script>
    function rowSelected(args) {
        var selectedrecords = this.getSelectedRecords();
        var memberName = document.getElementById("memberName");
        var memberEmail = document.getElementById("memberEmail");
        memberName.innerHTML = selectedrecords[0].Name;
        memberEmail.innerHTML = selectedrecords[0].Email;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidebar serves as a layout component, allowing us to render various components within its content area. Depending on the content element chosen, having the ability to dynamically manage actions. In your application, you're rendering HTML elements within the content, which enables you to dynamically update content values by altering the innerHTML in an HTML-based manner. This is the possible way approach to achieve your requirements effectively.